# Set user for pushing from GitLab CI with project deploy key

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently working on integrating GitLab CI for automated releases with a shell-based runner.

After getting successful tests for my build, I generate a new release to push it back to the repository. To do so, a deploy key with write access is configured for the repository.

Commits are using author data specific to the runner host, configured globally on the runner host (the corresponding user does not exist at GitLab itself). If these changes are pushed, the *Activity* section of the repository shows that the actual push has been done by one of the instance administrators (who initially configured the admin-specific stuff).

How can I configure/change this behaviour to push from the runner-specific user instead?